# Yii - how to include phpdocx files?

Tags: yii, yii-components, phpdocx

I'm trying to include phpdocx files in my Yii project.  On a standalone php script, all I have to do is

```
require_once 'phpdocx/classes/CreateDocx.inc';
```

Not sure how to do it with Yii.  I put the folder under protected/components/thirdparty/phpdocx.  And added the line above (with correct path) in config/main.php, but Yii can't find the rest of the .inc files.

How do I include those?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
define('PHPDOCX_INCLUDE_PATH', (dirname(Yii::app()->basePath)).'/components/thirdparty/phpdocx');

spl_autoload_unregister(array('YiiBase','autoload'));
require_once PHPDOCX_INCLUDE_PATH.'/classes/AutoLoader.inc';
spl_autoload_register(array('AutoLoader','load'));
spl_autoload_register(array('YiiBase', 'autoload'));

// your code
$docx = new CreateDocx();
$docx->addTemplate('files/mytemplate.docx');
```

Comment: try replace spl_autoload_register(array('YiiBase', 'autoload')); to the end of work with Docx

Comment: @user187809, and what class not able to load?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the namespacing version of Phpdocx, and then just load the library in  composer.json.